# Search function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just creating  a table with search and edit functions.  My solution has a problem the search  is not working properly .but if i remove `<EditableCell id={person.id} data={person.name}  />` this line from DisplayTable  class the search function will work but the edit function codes are written  in that class.  I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
*/
//Making the main component, InstantBox


 var InstantBox = React.createClass({

  doSearch:function(queryText)
  {
   console.log(queryText)
   //get query result
    var queryResult=[];
  this.props.data.forEach(function(person)
   {

   if(person.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryText)!=-1)
    queryResult.push(person);
  });

   this.setState({ query:queryText, data:queryResult })

  },

  handleClick: function() {
    this.setState({ showResults: true });     

   },
    getInitialState:function(){

     return{data:this.props.data,showResults: false}    
  },

    onChangeName:function(e){     
   this.setState({name:e.target.value})

  },
  onChangePhone:function(e){    
  this.setState({phone:e.target.value})
  },
  onChangeEmail:function(e){
  this.setState({email:e.target.value})
  },
  handleSubmit:function(e){

 if(this.state.name==null){

  alert("Data cannot be added without name");

 }else{

 this.setState({ showResults: false });
e.preventDefault();
this.state.data.push({name:this.state.name,phone:this.state.phone,email:this.state.email});
this.setState({name:'',phone:'',email:''})    
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert( xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

     xmlhttp.open("GET", "insert.php?n=" +           
     this.state.name+"&p="+this.state.phone+"&e="+this.state.email, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  },
  render:function(){


      return (

            <div id="wrapper">             

                <div className="InstantBox" >   
                <h3 className="head">Contact List</h3>  
                <label> search  </label>              
                <SearchBox query={this.state.query} doSearch={this.doSearch}/> 
        <EditableCell id={this.state.query}   />
                <label>     </label>              
                <input type="submit" value="ADD" onClick={this.handleClick} />  
                <p></p>                    
                <DisplayTable data={this.state.data}/>

             </div>
            <div >                    
                 { this.state.showResults ? 
                <Results onChangeName={this.onChangeName}
                onChangePhone={this.onChangePhone}
                onChangeEmail={this.onChangeEmail}
                handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  /> 
                : null }
            </div> 
           </div>


        );
     }
   });


 var Results = React.createClass({      
   render: function() {
    return (
        <div id="results" className="search-results">
           <form  onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>        
    <table className="addform">
    <thead>
         <tr> <th>Add New Contact</th> </tr>                 
        <tr><th><input type="text"  placeholder="Name" value={this.name}onChange=   
 {this.props.onChangeName}/></th> </tr>
        <tr><th><input type="text" placeholder="Phone" value={this.props.phone}onChange=

  {this.props.onChangePhone}/></th>  </tr>
        <tr><th><input type="text" placeholder="Email Name"  value={this.props.email}onChange=
   {this.props.onChangeEmail}/></th>  </tr>
        <tr><th><button >SAVE</button></th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
    </form> 
        </div>
    );
   },

   });
 var SearchBox = React.createClass({
  doSearch:function(){

    var query=this.refs.searchInput.getDOMNode().value; // this is the search text
    this.props.doSearch(query);


    },


   render:function(){

    return <input type="text" ref="searchInput" placeholder="Search Name" value=   
     {this.props.query} onChange={this.doSearch}/>
  }


});



 var EditableCell = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        isEditMode: false,
        data: ""
    };
   },
   componentWillMount: function () {
    this.setState({
        isEditMode: this.props.isEditMode,
        data: this.props.data


    });
   },
   handleEditCell: function (evt) {
      this.setState({isEditMode: true});

   },
  handleKeyDown: function (evt) {

    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 13: // Enter          

        case 9: // Tab
            this.setState({isEditMode: false});
            break;

    }
        if(evt.keyCode==13){

       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            alert( xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "update.php?n=" + this.state.data+"&i="+this.props.id, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

   },
  handleChange: function (evt) {
    this.setState({data: evt.target.value}); 

   },


   render: function () {
    var cellHtml;
    var current_data;
   var counter=0;

   //alert(this.props.data);

    if (this.state.isEditMode) {


        cellHtml = <input type='text' value={this.state.data}
            onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    }
    else {
        cellHtml = <div onClick={this.handleEditCell}>{this.state.data}</div>
    }
    return (
        <td>{cellHtml}</td>
        );
     }
  });



 var DisplayTable = React.createClass({

   render:function(){
    //making the rows to display

    var rows=[];
    this.props.data.forEach(function(person)
 {

    rows.push(<tr >
   <EditableCell id={person.id} data={person.name}  />

       <td><a href="url">Phone</a></td>
         <td><a href="url">email</a></td></tr>
        )
    }.bind(this));


    //returning the table
    return(


         <table className="tableFormt">
            <thead>            
                <tr>                       
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>             
            <tbody>{rows}
            </tbody>
        </table>        

        );      
      }
   });  



    React.renderComponent( <InstantBox data={result} id={result} /> ,document.body);
```

Comment: What is your exact issue? I've pasted the code into http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/8754/ and it searches okay..?

Comment: thanks for your reply . i seen the jsfiddle code . when i search for esther its still shows henrik that is my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to your problem:

1) pass a key property to `EditableCell` component:

```
<EditableCell id={person.id} data={person.name}  key={person.name}/>
```

2) implement `componentWillReceiveProps` in the `EditableCell` component:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
       this.setState({"data":nextProps.data});
 },
```

In your current code, in the first render the two rows are being rendered. When you filter the results, the first EditableCell is passed "Esther" as data property but state is not set. You are **only** setting state in componentDidMount function. So Henrik remains. The second row is not rendered because there is only 1 result.

Reading about reconciliation may also help : http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#problematic-case